# Sort array of hashes with nil values last

Tags: ruby, sorting, null

I wrote a method which sorts an array of hashes by given hash keys. The method should put `nil` values at the end.

```
def sort(records, *attrs)
  records.sort do |a,b|
    result = 0
    attrs.each do |attr|
      unless a[attr] == b[attr]
        result = if a[attr].nil?
                   1
                 elsif b[attr].nil?
                   -1
                 else
                  a[attr] <=> b[attr]
                 end
        break
      end
    end
    result
  end
end

p sort([{:a => 1},{:a => nil},{:a => 2}], :a)
#=> [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>nil}]
p sort([{:a => nil},{:a => 'x'},{:a => 'a'}], :a)
#=> [{:a=>"a"}, {:a=>"x"}, {:a=>nil}]
```

My solution looks quite complex. Is there a better way to achieve the ordering in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Set Unions

Looking at your code, when you loop through the attrs, you are breaking after you find the first key that is in `a` and in `b` and in the passed `attrs`.  This is also known as the `union` of the arrays.  As such you can simplify the inner loop with:

```
(attrs & a.keys & b.keys).first
```

#### Shorthand if/elseif syntax

You can use the keyword `then` in conjunction with `if` and `elsif` to cut down on the whitespace of your if-eslif chain. The syntax would look like:

```
if attr.nil? then 0
elsif a[attr].nil? then 1
elsif b[attr].nil? then -1
else a[attr] <=> b[attr] end
```

#### Putting it all together

```
def sort(records, *attrs)
  records.sort do |a, b|
    attr = (attrs & a.keys & b.keys).first
    if attr.nil? then 0
    elsif a[attr].nil? then 1
    elsif b[attr].nil? then -1
    else a[attr] <=> b[attr] end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the _union_ line with `attr = attrs.find { |e| a[e] != b[e] }`, which also works.

Answer (score 4):

You can create temporary sorting columns:

```
def sort records, *attrs
  records.sort_by do |h|
    h.values_at(*attrs).map do |v|
      v.nil? ? [2] : [1, v]
    end
  end
end
```

Here I added columns with values 1 or 2 to the left for higher priority -- could add to the right or even in between for more complex sorting.

Comment: The -1,0,1 values are the  the result of the manual `a<=>b` comparison happening in the sort block.  They are the expected return values.

Comment: @Zack, oh, understood. Rarely using `#sort` I forgot about that. Thank you for note.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. After all I implemented it the following way. It combines the solutions of Zack and Nakilon.

```
def sort(records, *attrs)
  records.sort do |a,b|
    k = attrs.find { |e| a[e] != b[e] }                    # 1.
    k ? [a[k] ? 0 : 1, a[k]] <=> [b[k] ? 0 : 1, b[k]] : 0  # 2.
  end
end
```

1. Select the attribute that differs (Similar to the union idea of Zack)
2. Introduce a pseudo value for comparison with `nil` values (Taken from Nakilons post)

Comment: What's wrong why Nakilon's answer? Using `sort` is kind of clunky when `sort_by` (a higher-level abstraction) can do the job just fine.

Comment: @tokland Nothing is wrong. It does the `nil` extra value for every attribute. When selecting the attribute that differs, you have to it just one time. It's only style not correctness.

On the other hand, my solution has some redunancy (`x[k] ? 0 : 1`) that Nakilon approach avoids. :-)

Comment: While shorter, I feel like this version is much harder to read and understand.